# how to get the text input value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i have written this code , i have a text field and when i enter something in text box and click submit.the value of text box should alert message box.
how to do this? pls help me

here is what i have tried

```
<form name="input" action="#" method="post" 
    <input type="text" name="cost" value=" ">
</form>
```

javascript:

```
   var trlist = document.getElementsByName("cost");
   alert(trlist);
```

How to get values from textbox and print it in alertbox?

Comment: You should have just searched for the answer in StackOverflow, this is a very common question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is better that you declared `id` inside the  `<input type="text" name="cost" value=" ">`

```
<form name="input" action="#" method="post" 
    <input type="text" name="cost" value=" " id="cost">
</form>
```

and after you call with :

```
var trlist = document.getElementById("cost").value;
   alert(trlist);
```

[EXample](http://jsfiddle.net/mrk1989/aK4yy/1/)

In your case when you use `getElementbyname` return `undefined`
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mrk1989/aK4yy/)

And if you want to use `getElementbyname` [solution on JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mrk1989/aK4yy/3/)

Comment: What is `getElementbyname`?

Comment: and why is `getElementById` *better* ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `value` property.

You should also note that `getElementsByName` returns a `HTMLCollection` and as such you need to get the correct node - in your case the first (`0`). [Docs for `getElementByName` here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName)

So you should be doing

```
var trlist = document.getElementsByName("cost")[0].value;
alert(trlist);
```

[Docs for `HTMLInputElement` here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.value` to get the value

```
 document.getElementsByName.('cost')[0].value;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a `value` property for a single form input element:

```
alert(trlist[0].value);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var trlist = document.getElementsByName('cost')[0].value;
alert(trlist);
```

`getElementsByName()` returns an HTMLCollection, which doesn't have a value property. HTMLCollection mimics an Array, so its elements can be accessed using the array notation `array[index]`

`document.getElementsByName('cost')[0]` returns the first element with `name` attribute set to `cost`, which in your case is `<input type="text" name="cost" value=" ">`

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the form tag first

```
<form name="input" action="#" method="post" >
    <input type="text" name="cost" value=" ">
</form>
```

Use the value property

```
var trlist = document.getElementsByName("cost").value;
alert(trlist);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = $('textBob id').text();
alert(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can get value of "cost" to variable name "trlist" and i just display it using **alert**

var trlist = document.getElementById("cost").value;
alert(trlist);

**getElementById** is keyword to get value

Comment: to use `getElementById` the element needs to have the id property set `<input id="cost">`

also you're answer doesn't add anything to the already accepted answer.